# Partially strict marshmallow schema

Tags: python, python-2.7, validation, flask, marshmallow

I have a Flask Rest Api which uses marshmallow for serialization-desirealization. The Api recieves a batch of items.

**I'd like to perform a strict validation on the input schema per item instead of on the entire request.** 
The purpose of this is to allow me to do fine-grained error handling, i.e. process the entire batch request and also return validation errors for the bad Items.

Example Time!

Suppose this is my main Rest Json Request Schema (note the list of `Nested` fields) -

```
from marshmallow import Schema

class MyRequestSchema(Schema):
    class Meta:
        strict = True
    items = fields.List(fields.Nested(MyItemSchema), required=True)
    id = fields.String(required=False, missing=None)
    meta_field = fields.Integer(required=False, missing=False)
```

And this is my `Nested field` schema-

```
class MyItemSchema(Schema):
    class Meta:
        strict = True
    name = fields.String(required=False, missing=None)
    flag = fields.Bool(required=False, missing=False)
```

what I'd like is for marshmallow to 1) deserialize the entire request schema and 2) Supply me with per-item schema validation errors or a serialized object.
Using this behavior, I would process each `Item`. For every Item which contains validation errors, I'll return an error object and for the valid Items I'll return a proper response Item.

So for a request like this -

```
{
  "id": "d6f6f80c558a11",
  "meta_field": 42,
  "items": [
    {
      "name": "abc",
      "flag": true
    },
    {
      "bad_field": "bad_value"
    }
  ]
}
```

I'd like to return a response along the lines of this -

```
{
  "id": "d6f6f80c558a11",
  "result_items": [
    {
      "name": "abc",
      "result": "Great Success!"
    },
    {
      "schema_validation_error": {
        "details": {
          "listings": {
            "0": {
              "name": [
                "Missing data for required field."
              ],
              "flag": [
                "Missing data for required field."
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "message": "Invalid Item"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Does marshmallow support this behaviour?

Any suggestions on implementing this?

Ideally, I'd like an answer which embraces as much of Flask+Marshmallow as possible (instead of implementing the logic myself)

Thanks!